# Access entire sublist of two dimensional array Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

I am stumped. This should be simple. I am trying to access the entire sublists/shortlists (not sure what they are called) that make up my 2D array. All of the reference I have seen shows me how to simply select or print row/column items from the array. Thanks

```
int brobes[][]  = {{0, 1, 0}, {4, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
int my0[] = brobes[0];
println(brobes[0]);
//hoping it will print: {0,1,0} and so forth
```

Comment: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question. While Processing shares some syntax with Java, [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java), so Java answers aren't always the best fit for Processing questions.

Comment: What does it print instead of what you expect?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking it. Your code prints this out:

```
[0] 0
[1] 1
[2] 0
```

When you print an array in Processing, it prints each index of the array on it own line. This is the correct behavior, and it means that you're correctly  getting the array out of your 2D array.

(This is more complicated if it's an array of Objects instead of ints, in which case you have to use the [**`printArray()`**](https://processing.org/reference/printArray_.html) function.)

If you want something other than the default printing format, then you're going to have to do it yourself:

```
String s = "{";
for(int i : brobes[0]){
   s += " " + i;
}
s += " }";
println(s);
```

You could also use a Java solution from the other answers, but that prevents you from later deploying as JavaScript.

But if all you want to do is get the array out of the 2D array, **you're already doing that**. You can then use this array exactly like you'd use any other array.

Answer (score 0):

**If your goal is only printing one row of the array then use**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(brobes[0]));
```

**If your goal is only printing the hole array then use the**
[Arrays.deepToString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method....

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(brobes));
```

this will print a pretty representation of the array

> [[0, 1, 0], [4, 4, 4], [4, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

**OR use a double loop if you want to check/manipulate/ operate with every element in the array....**

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int brobes[][] = { { 0, 1, 0 }, { 4, 4, 4 }, { 4, 5, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
for (int i = 0; i < brobes.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < brobes[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.println(brobes[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("======================");
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The below solution is in Java. Probably something similar could be done in a different language (though not entirely sure :))

It is because `brobes[0]` is itself an array. `System.out.println` will print the default toString method used in array which is a non readable format.

You can use Arrays.toString to convert the array to string.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(brobes[0]));
```

Comment: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question. While Processing shares some syntax with Java, [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java), so Java answers aren't always the best fit for Processing questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info @KevinWorkman I looked at it being marked as Java, and went ahead with the Java implementation of the same.

Comment: Thank you again. I was overthinking it. Everything works thanks to all of your suggestions!

Answer (score -2):

First, try changing the brackets after the array to make them before the array, like this:   int[] myo = brobes[0];

If that doesn't work, why not just traverse the array with loops?
What is the end goal here?

Comment: Additionally, try printing System.out.println(my0);  That should give you what you want.

Comment: Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question. While Processing shares some syntax with Java, [Processing != Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java), so Java answers aren't always the best fit for Processing questions.

Comment: Yes this works. My end goal is to simply access different sublists (ruleSets) incrementally in my 2D array so I can input them into a Cellular Automata algorithm to update patterns iteratively.

Comment: Okay, so you should loop through the array, using a variable as the index, then you can simply store each row into your algorithm like store(array[x]) where store is a function that stores a row.  I'm glad to hear that it worked :)